# How to use Qt C++ controls in Qml?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

UI of my application is implemented in QML. It has a large nested menu with many items in many levels of hierarchy. This menu implemented in QML. Filling and updating of this menu take several seconds. It is too slow. I want to implement this menu in C++. 
I know how to implement simple QML control in C++: I should extend class QQuickPaintedItem.
But the menu is not such a simple class. It contains children.

How to implement the menu for QML in C++? Can I use QMenu C++ class in QML?

Comment: I highly advice you to read [QmlBook](https://qmlbook.github.io/), especially the [Qt and C++](https://qmlbook.github.io/ch16-qtcpp/qtcpp.html). Yan yes, you cannot use QWidget controls with QtQuick. You should use native QML components, like [Menu](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html)

Comment: QmlBook contains info about creating new QML classes from C++. But in chapter 17 [Extending QML with C++](http://qmlbook.github.io/ch17-extensions/extensions.html#fileio-implementation). Unfortunately, an example in this chapter does not relate to creating new GUI elements from C++.

Comment: Yes, that is it. The GUI elements are created in the same way. But you must derive the custom GUI item from QQuickItem (the best and faster way, but you have to know OpenGL) or from QQuickPaintedItem (slower but easier way, QPainter based, actually the canvas will be implicitly converted to a OpenGL texture)

Comment: Did you read about [compiling QML source code into the final binary](https://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/) ?